# Does Tomcat uses the java under the symbolic link /usr/bin/java?

Tags: linux, tomcat, java, symlink

I have two linux servers having a tomcat 7.0.42 running with two java applications packaged in 2 WAR files. I'm using JDK7u25 on linux, but one of them still has a symbolic link to jdk1.4.2 (I have no admin rights, so I can't change it).

The Linux server that has the correct symbolic link /usr/bin/java --> jdk 7, works fine. The applications are running without any issues.

The other Linux server that has /usr/bin/java --> jdk1.4.2, BUT has a JAVA_HOME in tomcat set to jdk 7, (JAVA_HOME=//jdk_1.7.0.25/), throws me an error when deploying my apps. My apps need the Forkjoin API (available only in jdk 7).

The only difference I noticed between these two servers, is the symbolic links.

I copied the working tomcat (directory + apps + JDK) to the not working server, and set the JAVA_HOME to the imported working JDK, but still not working... It keeps throwing me error message and can't run the apps.

Here are the logs, although I think it's not explicit enough to understand what I am doing.

```
 WARNING: Exception encountered when executing an asynchronous task
com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetRuntimeException: com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.MergeException: [rcpcn0c-29706] Could not merge commit 2 from BoNYslNonCashCollateralsCube( r9szn0c-50673) in BoNYslNonCashCollateralsDistributedCube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.consume(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:493)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.consume(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:408)
    at jsr166.impl.SingleConsumerQueue.tryConsume(SingleConsumerQueue.java:249)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.compute(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:439)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableRecursiveAction.executeTask(CancellableRecursiveAction.java:28)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableForkJoinTask.exec(CancellableForkJoinTask.java:79)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:990)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1631)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)
Caused by: com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.MergeException: [rcpcn0c-29706] Could not merge commit 2 from BoNYslNonCashCollateralsCube( r9szn0c-50673) in BoNYslNonCashCollateralsDistributedCube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$DistributedTransactionManager.mergeDimensionsInCube(ADistributedActivePivot.java:1014)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$DistributedTransactionManager.onInitialRemoteCommit(ADistributedActivePivot.java:861)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.consume(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:479)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The measure CollateralValue.SUM belongs to more than one cube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.PolymorphicLocalityIdentifier.validateAndContribute(PolymorphicLocalityIdentifier.java:235)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$MergeDimensionsTask.compute(ADistributedActivePivot.java:770)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableRecursiveAction.executeTask(CancellableRecursiveAction.java:28)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableForkJoinTask.exec(CancellableForkJoinTask.java:79)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:360)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:691)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$DistributedTransactionManager.mergeDimensionsInCube(ADistributedActivePivot.java:1009)
    ... 11 more
```

Aug 07, 2013 8:18:11 PM com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.SafeBroadcastingTask compute
INFO: Exception encountered during a broadcasting task. Retrying ...
com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetRuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetRuntimeException: com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.MergeException: [rcpcn0c-29706] Could not merge commit 2 from BoNYslNonCashCollateralsCube( r9szn0c-50673) in BoNYslNonCashCollateralsDistributedCube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.RemoteInstanceDistributionManager.onMembersChanged(RemoteInstanceDistributionManager.java:217)
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger$MembersNotificationAction$1.compute(ADistributedMessenger.java:1046)
    at jsr166e.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:161)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:345)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(ForkJoinTask.java:756)
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger$MembersNotificationAction.execute(ADistributedMessenger.java:1050)
    at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$ConsumerProcedure.consume(DeferredActionQueue.java:181)
    at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$ConsumerProcedure.consume(DeferredActionQueue.java:157)
    at jsr166.impl.SingleConsumerQueue.tryConsume(SingleConsumerQueue.java:249)
    at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue.executeAll(DeferredActionQueue.java:68)
    at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$DeferredExecutionAction.compute(DeferredActionQueue.java:274)
    at jsr166e.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:161)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:360)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:691)
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.SafeBroadcastingTask.compute(SafeBroadcastingTask.java:101)
    at jsr166e.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:65)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:990)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1631)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetRuntimeException: com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.MergeException: [rcpcn0c-29706] Could not merge commit 2 from BoNYslNonCashCollateralsCube( r9szn0c-50673) in BoNYslNonCashCollateralsDistributedCube
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.future.impl.ACompositeFuture.getResult(ACompositeFuture.java:155)
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.future.impl.ACompositeFuture.getOrCancel(ACompositeFuture.java:251)
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.sendMessages(ADistributedMessenger.java:793)
    at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.sendMessage(ADistributedMessenger.java:864)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.RemoteInstanceDistributionManager.onMembersChanged(RemoteInstanceDistributionManager.java:215)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetRuntimeException: com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.MergeException: [rcpcn0c-29706] Could not merge commit 2 from BoNYslNonCashCollateralsCube( r9szn0c-50673) in BoNYslNonCashCollateralsDistributedCube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.consume(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:493)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.consume(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:408)
    at jsr166.impl.SingleConsumerQueue.tryConsume(SingleConsumerQueue.java:249)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.compute(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:439)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableRecursiveAction.executeTask(CancellableRecursiveAction.java:28)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableForkJoinTask.exec(CancellableForkJoinTask.java:79)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.MergeException: [rcpcn0c-29706] Could not merge commit 2 from BoNYslNonCashCollateralsCube( r9szn0c-50673) in BoNYslNonCashCollateralsDistributedCube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$DistributedTransactionManager.mergeDimensionsInCube(ADistributedActivePivot.java:1014)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$DistributedTransactionManager.onInitialRemoteCommit(ADistributedActivePivot.java:861)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.DistributedDimensionsManager$ApplyInitialMessageTask.consume(DistributedDimensionsManager.java:479)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The measure CollateralValue.SUM belongs to more than one cube
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.distribution.impl.PolymorphicLocalityIdentifier.validateAndContribute(PolymorphicLocalityIdentifier.java:235)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$MergeDimensionsTask.compute(ADistributedActivePivot.java:770)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableRecursiveAction.executeTask(CancellableRecursiveAction.java:28)
    at jsr166.cancellable.impl.CancellableForkJoinTask.exec(CancellableForkJoinTask.java:79)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:360)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:691)
    at com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.ADistributedActivePivot$DistributedTransactionManager.mergeDimensionsInCube(ADistributedActivePivot.java:1009)
    ... 11 more

and the other repeated log error:

```
    SEVERE: HelloMessage [HelloMessage-rcpcn0c-47329-62] could not be transmitted
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.future.impl.ACompositeFuture.getResult(ACompositeFuture.java:159)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.future.impl.ACompositeFuture.getOrCancel(ACompositeFuture.java:251)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.sendMessages(ADistributedMessenger.java:793)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.sendMessage(ADistributedMessenger.java:864)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.broadcast(ADistributedMessenger.java:881)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.JGroupsMessenger.ensureMembersCommunication(JGroupsMessenger.java:174)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger$MembersNotificationAction.execute(ADistributedMessenger.java:1004)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$ConsumerProcedure.consume(DeferredActionQueue.java:181)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$ConsumerProcedure.consume(DeferredActionQueue.java:157)
        at jsr166.impl.SingleConsumerQueue.tryConsume(SingleConsumerQueue.java:249)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue.executeAll(DeferredActionQueue.java:68)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$DeferredExecutionAction.compute(DeferredActionQueue.java:274)
        at jsr166e.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:161)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:360)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:691)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.SafeBroadcastingTask.compute(SafeBroadcastingTask.java:101)
        at jsr166e.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:65)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:990)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1631)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)

    Aug 07, 2013 8:18:29 PM com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.SafeBroadcastingTask compute
    INFO: Exception encountered during a broadcasting task. Retrying ...
    com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetRuntimeException: Could not connect to remote instances
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.JGroupsMessenger.ensureMembersCommunication(JGroupsMessenger.java:188)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger$MembersNotificationAction.execute(ADistributedMessenger.java:1004)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$ConsumerProcedure.consume(DeferredActionQueue.java:181)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$ConsumerProcedure.consume(DeferredActionQueue.java:157)
        at jsr166.impl.SingleConsumerQueue.tryConsume(SingleConsumerQueue.java:249)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue.executeAll(DeferredActionQueue.java:68)
        at jsr166.impl.DeferredActionQueue$DeferredExecutionAction.compute(DeferredActionQueue.java:274)
        at jsr166e.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:161)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:360)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:691)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.SafeBroadcastingTask.compute(SafeBroadcastingTask.java:101)
        at jsr166e.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:65)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:264)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:990)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1631)
        at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.future.impl.ACompositeFuture.getResult(ACompositeFuture.java:159)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.future.impl.ACompositeFuture.getOrCancel(ACompositeFuture.java:251)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.sendMessages(ADistributedMessenger.java:793)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.sendMessage(ADistributedMessenger.java:864)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.ADistributedMessenger.broadcast(ADistributedMessenger.java:881)
        at com.quartetfs.tech.distribution.messenger.impl.JGroupsMessenger.ensureMembersCommunication(JGroupsMessenger.java:174)
        ... 16 more
```

Can it be from the java under /usr/bin/javaeven if I have set JAVA_HOME to the right place? I can't find how tomcat really uses java...

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat, as Stephen indicated, uses multiple different ways, depending on the server configuration, to determine what java is being used.

In most cases, I would start by checking on the *working* server for the existence of $JAVA_HOME, as well as custom $PATH settings.  Check the usual suspects:  /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*, .bash*, .profile or the like.

You may even find that JAVA_HOME is specified both at the user level, but also at the service level in the init scripts if you are running it as an actual service.

At this moment, there are many variables that are unanswered in your question:

1.) Are you running the process as the same user in both locations?
2.) Are the users configured identically in both locations, with the same PATH precedence and ENV variables?
3.) Are the init scripts the same?

By providing us as much detail as possible, we can provide a more complete/thorough response.

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way.  The OP should check how the Tomcat scripts he is using *actually* working.  You should not be encouraging him to solve the problem by guesswork.

Comment: There is no guesswork being done here, there is investigation.  We are not aware of how the scripts are being used in the first place.  Has the process been daemonized, or is it being run via sh $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh(and shutdown.sh), which in the case of startup.sh, it would then invoke catalina.sh.  By asking him to do investigation, we are becoming aware of the actual environment, and able to provide a more clear answer.  If we want to make assumptions, then yes, we can simply assume that hes doing it X way, and Y solution is correct.  We do not have that data.

Comment: Well ... I can tell you that you've made two guesses in your suggested approach.  1)  You guessed that the two machines are running package-installed Tomcats on the same (or similar) distros ... so that the installations are likely to look similar.  2)  You've guessed that scripts he is using depend on environment variable settings in "the usual suspects".  On RedHat-based distros, they don't.  He won't find them that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Tomcat uses the java under the symbolic link /usr/bin/java?

It entirely depends on how you have configured Tomcat and how you are launching it.

But the good news that all of that happens in shell scripts that you can easily read ... and if necessary "hack" to figure out which `java` command is being used.  Start with the launch command or init.d script or whatever, and trace it through.

Also, bear in mind that a lot of this stuff is dependent on the Linux distro that you are using, and how they have put together the Tomcat "package".